# Synchronous AJAX...I know that sounds crazy

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have web methods that are called via AJAX in a .Net 4.0 web app.  In many cases, the AJAX calls are made repeatedly in a for loop.  My problem is, the information the web method is syncing to my server is time stamped and therefore must be synced in the order in which I am sending it to AJAX.  Unfortunately, it seems whatever finishes first, simply finishes first and the time stamps are all out of order.  I need to basically queue up my AJAX requests so that they execute in order rather than Asynchronously, which I know is the A in AJAX so this might be a totally dumb question.

How do I force the order of execution for AJAX calls done in a for loop?

Edit:  Some code

```
                    for (var i = 0; i < itemCnt - 1; i++) {

                    try {
                        key = items[i];
                        item = localStorage.getItem(key);
                        vals = item.split(",");
                        type = getType(key);


                        if (type == "Status") {
                            var Call = key.substring(7, 17);
                            var OldStat = vals[0];
                            var NewStat = vals[1];
                            var Date1 = vals[2];
                            var Time1 = vals[3];
                            var miles = vals[4];

                            try {
                                stat(Call, OldStat, NewStat, Date1, Time1, miles, key);

                            }
                            catch (e) {
                                alert("Status " + e);
                                return;
                            }

                        }
                        else if (type == "Notes") {
                            var Call = key.substring(6, 16);
                            var Notes = item;
                            try {
                                addNotes(Call, Notes);
                            }
                            catch (e) {
                                alert("Notes " + e);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        else if (key == "StartNCTime" || key == "EndNCTime") {
                            var TechID = vals[0];
                            var Date = vals[1];
                            var Time = vals[2];
                            var Activity = vals[3];
                            var Location = vals[4];
                            var Type = vals[5];

                            try {
                                logTime(TechID, Date, Time, Activity, Location, Type, 
                            }
                            catch (e) {
                                alert(key + ' ' + e);
                                return;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                    catch (e) {
                        alert(key + ' ' + e);
                        return;
                    }
                }

function stat(Call, OldStat, NewStat, Date1, Time1, miles, key) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "Service.asmx/update_Stat",
    data: '{ CallNumber:"' + Call + '", OldStat:"' + OldStat + '", NewStat:"' + NewStat + '", Date1:"' + Date1 + '", Time1:"' + Time1 + '", Miles: "' + miles + '"}',
    success: function (data) { },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert("Sync Update Stat: " + err.Message);
        location = location;
    }
});
}

function logTime(TechID, Date, Time, Activity, Location, Type, key) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "Service.asmx/nonCallTime",
    data: '{ TechID:"' + TechID + '", Date1:"' + Date + '", Time1:"' + Time + '", Activity:"' + Activity + '", Location:"' + Location + '", Type: "' + Type + '"}',
    success: function (data) { },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert("Sync Non Call Time: " + err.Message);
        location = location;
    }
});
}

function addNotes(Call, Notes) {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "Service.asmx/addNote",
    data: '{ Call:"' + Call + '", Notes:"' + Notes + '"}',
    success: function (data) { },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert("Sync Notes: " + err.Message);
        location = location;
    }
});
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use callbacks.

```
function ajax1(){
   //..some code
   //on ajax success:
   ajax2();
}

//etcetera...
```

Or might I suggest using a javascript library like `jQuery` to synchronize your ajax requests for you.

Comment: I don't know the exact number of iterations in the for loop until run time nor do I really know which ajax call needs to be made until each iteration of the for loop when I determine the type of information contained in it.  I will edit my post to include some sample code.

Comment: You mentioned using jQuery to synchronize.  How might that look?  Sorry, I'm a 100% self taught noob.  :)

Answer (score 1):

set the third parameter in xmlhttp object's open method to false to make it synchronous.

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: @Raynos this was just to inform OP about the existence of syncrhonous ajax, read the title of question. However I would not necessarily use this. What is wrong with telling people it exists, irrespective of it is good or bad?

I'd rather save all responses and process it according to timestamp after all response has been received.

Comment: The problem is your promoting bad practices without even mentioning it's a bad practice.

Comment: best practices might not fit into all situations.

Comment: Correct, but ajax isn't a best practice. It's the only practice. sjax is simply stupid and a dirty hack that should never be used.

Answer (score 0):

A general pattern for making actions serial would be such:

```
function doAjax(data, cb) {
  ...
  // when ready call cb
}

(function (next) {
  var xhr = doAjax(data, next);
})(function (next) {
  var xhr = doAjax(data, next);
})(function (next) {
  doAjax(data);
});
```

Doing so in a for loop would require recursion.

```
(function next() {
  if ( i < n ) {
    doAjax(data[i++], next);
  }
})();
```